# if $\lim_{n}{a_n}=a$, then what can you say about $\lim_{n}{\ln{a_n}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

So recently I am studying real analysis and I have a thought:

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers where $a_n >0$, $\forall n\in\Bbb N$ and $\lim_{n}{a_n}=a>0$. Then is the sequence $(\ln{a_n})_{n\in \Bbb N} $ convergent to $\ln{a}$?

My attempt:

Let $\epsilon >0$, then
$$a(1-e^{-\epsilon})>a(1-e^{0})=0$$
Then there exists $N\in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have
$$|a_n-a|<a(1-e^{-\epsilon})$$
$$\Rightarrow a(e^{-\epsilon}-1)<a_n-a<a(1-e^{-\epsilon})=a(\frac{e^\epsilon-1}{e^\epsilon})<a(e^\epsilon-1)$$
$$\Rightarrow ae^{-\epsilon}<a_n<ae^\epsilon
\Rightarrow e^{-\epsilon}<\frac{a_n}{a}<e^\epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon<\ln{\frac{a_n}{a}}<\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow |\ln{a_n}-\ln{a}|<\epsilon$$
Therefore $\lim_n{\ln{a_n}}=\ln{a}$.

Please help me to check the correctness of this. Many thanks!

Comment: What does lim_n denote?

Comment: @Alephnull limit as $n$ approaches infinity

Comment: Welll if it exists it will obviously be ln(a), Must it exist?.Consider cases above and below 0.

Comment: @Alephnull *By assumption*, $a>0$.

Comment: @Clement C. perhaps my problem is beter.

Comment: @Alephnull Maybe. But that is not what is asked. I am sure a lot of questions on the site have better variants than the one asked, and I am also sure that is beyond the point.

Comment: @Clement C. Whatever

Comment: (also, as a remark: "below $0$" cannot happen, if it exists the limit $a$ must satisfy $a\geq 0$. The only possible "border case" would be $a=0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a more general case, if $f$ is a continuous function at $a$ then

$$\lim_n f(a_n)=f(a).$$

Indeed, when $f$ is continue at $a$ you have

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a).$$

Let's take $a_n$ such that $\lim a_n=a$.

Let's fix $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$such that

$$\forall x,\quad \vert x-a\vert \leq \delta\Rightarrow \vert f(x)-f(a)\vert \leq \epsilon.$$

Plus,

$$\exists N_\delta\in \mathbb N, \quad \forall n\geq N_\delta, \quad \vert a_n-a\vert\leq \delta.$$

So

$$\forall n\geq N_\delta, \quad \vert f(a_n)-f(a)\vert \leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: This is a standard result. For an $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-proof: $f$ is continous at $a$, so for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x)-f(a)\rvert \leq \varepsilon$ for any $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $\lvert x-a\rvert \leq \delta$. Now, fix any $\varepsilon > 0$, "get" the corresponding $\delta > 0$; since $a_n \to_{n\to\infty} a$, there exists $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $\lvert a_n-a\rvert \leq \delta$...

Comment: Most probably this wonderful result still is out of the OP's scope...

Comment: I edited to add the proof